# Can I do a Date Check on a TextBox with a onBlur event?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

I want to do a Date Check on a TextBox with a onBlur event. I am not sure how to check the textbox in javascript on the aspx side.  This is what I have so far

```
TodayDate= new Date();
function checkEnteredDate() {
if (document.getElementById('txtDate') > TodayDate) {
alert("You cannot select a date later than today.");
document.getElementById(TodayDate);
} 
}
```

This is already a javascript function, I just cannot get the value in the textbox for a comparison.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try passing the "this" to the function:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" onblur="CheckEnteredDate(this);" runat="server" />
```

**Edit**: Here's how the javascript function would use that (roughly):

```
function CheckEnteredDate(passed) {
    if (new Date(passed.value) > new Date()) {
        alert('Date greater than today');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, force of habit. :)  Corrected my example.

Comment: The Date() constructor expects the number of milliseconds since 1970.  Do you really think the user is going to type that in?!

Comment: @Josh Stodola - nope, try passing in a string: document.write(new Date("12 Jan 2007 12:15")); will output Fri Jan 12 2007 12:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) on my browser.

Comment: What are you talking about?  This: alert(new Date('1/1/2009').toString()); Displays "Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 CST 2009"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/) library to do date validation on the client-side like this...

```
function checkEnteredDate() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('txtDate');

  if(Date.parse(elem.value) > Date.today()) {
      alert("You cannot select a date later than today.");
      elem.select();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft Ajax, Date parsing is already handled by the provided javascript reference libraries.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" onblur="CheckEnteredDate(this);" runat="server" />
```

Then on the function call:

```
function CheckEnteredDate(passed) {
    var value = Date.parseLocale(passed.value, 'd');
    if (isNaN(value))
        alert('Not a valid date.');
    if (value > new Date())
        alert('You cannot select a date later than today.');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to add a function call to this to the onBlur event for the textbox.

Comment: the function is already being fired.  I just dont know how to call what is in the textbox

Answer (score -1):

When you pass textbox to document.getElementById, it returns an HTML object not the text inside the textbox. Use value property to get the value entered by the user. See below:

```
function checkEnteredDate() 
{
    var inputDate = document.getElementById('txtDate');
    if(inputDate == '')
    {
        alert('You must specify date.');
        return false;
    }

    inputDate = new Date(inputDate);
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //By default today's date will have time portion as well.

    if(inputDate > today)
    {
        alert('You can not select a date later than today');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```